# How to scale vectors in VectorPlot?

Tags: plotting

I generated some pics from 2 datum，one in $x$ direction and the other in $y$，so I used the commands:

```
exfield = Range[200];
polarplane = Range[200];
Get["C:\\Users\\dc\\Desktop\\polarplane.dat"];
Get["C:\\Users\\dc\\Desktop\\exfield.dat"];
xx = Table[
Transpose[{exfield[[25, i]], polarplane[[25, i]]}], {i, 71}];
ListVectorPlot[xx]
```

to get the vector field. But one problem here is, all the pics generated by the commands share the same maximum length of the vector. I can only see the orientation change but no magnitude change. I need a cartain standard (for instance, 1 cm vector length for the maximum data value $a_{max}$) to generate all the pics, so I can see the relative magnitude change. But I couldn't find the options. Have anyone encountered this same problem? Thank you.
And the sample datum are like:

```
 exfield[[001]] = {              
{
   a11,
   ……，
   a1i，
},
{
   a21,
   ……，
   a2i，
 },
   ……
 {
   ai1,
   ……，
   aii，
  },
 }
```

and the sample data:

[data](http://dropbox.com/s/m3p34ncas3qd8qm/datum.rar)

Comment: Could you maybe post `polarplane.dat` and `exfield.dat` somewhere (e.g. Pastebin)?

Comment: Oh, you finally come! Why not log in？

Comment: it's quite a large file, tons of datum, I am trying to find a place to upload the file

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3p34ncas3qd8qm/datum.rar    here, and, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `VectorScale` option for `ListVectorPlot` to control the scaling of vector sizes.

```
ListVectorPlot[Table[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}], 
 VectorScale -> .05]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListVectorPlot[Table[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}], 
 VectorScale -> .1]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is a fleshed out version:

Gather some data:

```
xxs = Table[Transpose[{exfield[[#, i]], polarplane[[#, i]]}], {i, 71}] & /@Range[27,35];
```

Find the relevant max vector sizes.

```
scales = With[{s = Max@Apply[Norm@#&,#,{2}] & /@ xxs}, s/Max@s];
```

Plot the vector fields, with a couple of fiddle factors for arrowhead size and absolute vector length:

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  MapThread[
   ListVectorPlot[#1, VectorScale -> #2, 
     VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[#2 0.015]] &, {xxs, 0.3 scales}], 3]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a little different from OP's intention: he wants the length of arrows to somewhat represent the size of the vector.

Comment: sorry I didn't put it clear, what i mean is i wanna use the same standard to present all the vectors in different plots.  thank you anyway

Comment: You can use the `VectorScale` to adjust the scale to the relative maximum size of the largest vector from each set of data.

Comment: Er…we can also use `Norm` instead of `EuclideanDistance`, right?

Comment: @xzczd Yes certainly :)

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED, THANK YOU SO MUCH :)

Comment: @user49114 Glad we could help.